# slimScroll 'auto': div height in percentages to work on iPhone and desktop; pushes bottom div down

Tags: jquery, html, css

Apologies for the title but I couldn't think of a better way to word it. I recently stumbled upon Firebase and wanted to have a go making a simple shopping list app so my wife and I could add/remove items to it whether we were at work, home or out and on our phones.

I have created this fiddle to show what I am currently doing: http://jsfiddle.net/YJQ8R/6/

I have a container div that wraps everything:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
    height: 668px;
}
```

Which is modified as follows for the iPhone:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px){
    #container {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Along with some code I found online to disable the pinch-zoom to make it behave more like a native app, which is only added if the browser is iPhone:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

The shopping list items get added to this div:

```
#shoppingListContents {
    min-height: 70%;
    max-height: 70%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

When trying to use slimScroll as follows (commented out in the fiddle as I couldn't see how to include it):

```
$("#shoppingListContents").slimScroll({
        height: 'auto',
        wheelStep: 2
 });
```

to accommodate for the percentage height div, it pushes the form way down below the bottom as showin in the following image:

[image: shopping list form pushed down]

It worked okay when I used a constant height for the slimScroll but wanted to avoid that for the iPhone.

Ultimately what I would like to achieve is the use of slimScroll on the #shoppingListContents div which will take up about 70% of the container with the form at the bottom taking up 25% or so.

Am open to any and all criticisms/suggestions on anything as every day is a good day to learn to do things better!

NB. Stripped out the Firebase stuff as it's not relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure this is probably horrible but I was able to pretty much solve my issue with the following:

```
if(navigator.platform === "iPhone") {
    containerHeight = $(window).height();
    formHeight = 0.24*containerHeight;
    listHeight = 0.7*containerHeight - 40;

    $("#container").css({"height": containerHeight});
    $("#shoppingListContents").css({"min-height": listHeight});
    $("#shoppingListContents").css({"max-height": listHeight});
    $("#shoppingListForm").css({"height": formHeight});
}
```

70% of the container for the list height was pushing the the form outside it so that's why there is the 40 px offset. By then setting the slimScroll height to listHeight I was able to get slimScroll working on my iPhone but it was really slow and actually took away from the normal browser scroll so I only add it for the desktop version.